# Is there a function similar to Oracle's trunc(sysdate) in mysql

Tags: mysql

In Oracle I can query like:

```
Select * from Orders where trunc(createdDate) = trunc(sysdate)
```

and I get all orders created today.

How to do the same in MySql?

So far I can only find like currentdate() = '07-05-2017', I don't want to hard code the date.

Thank you,

Dapid Candra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function returns the date part of any datetime value and [curdate()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function returns the current date, so no need to truncate its result:

```
... date(createdDate)=curdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use MySQL's `DATE()` function (along with `NOW()` function to get the current date). [Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) the documentation.

> Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.

Your query would be:

```
Select * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE DATE(createdDate) = DATE(NOW())
```

**Update**

As suggested by @Rahul, we can replace `DATE(NOW())` with `CURDATE()` as it returns date without timestamp, e.g.:

```
Select * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE DATE(createdDate) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a bit faster

```
Select * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE createdDate >= curdate();
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why this one would be faster? Thanks, Fran.

Comment: I think because i call only one function, not 2 or 3.

Comment: Not using a function on a column gives the query optimizer access to an index on that column - providing performance benefits. If you use a function on that column you lose that advantage. Research the term "sargable".

Comment: Thanks @used-by-already , i knew about LIKE and index, but not about functions and index. I thought it was "only" about function's performance cost.